# SQL Server Query for Mutual Matches in the same Table (2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have a table with following columns in Tenants Table.

```
TenantID
Name
address
Current_Bedrooms
Bedrooms_Needed
Current_City
City_Needed
```

For a given row, how can we write a query that will find the match the bedrooms_Needed with Current_Bedrooms **(same with city)** in other rows

example

```
Select * from Tenants where Current_Bedrooms = Bedrooms_Needed and TenantID = 1234
```

Comment: Its a bit unclear what you're going for here.  The query you've written will do exactly what you say you want.  I wonder however if you are needing something that will join a supplier of rooms with someone who needs rooms.

Comment: why do you have two column for the bedrooms and city. `Bedrooms_Needed` and `City_Needed` should be parameter in the query

Comment: Also find mutual matches for a given tenantID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want the tenants to 'swap' with eachother?
You can join the tenants table with itself (aliased as `t1` and `t2`), while specifying the matching criteria as the join condition:

```
Select T1.Name As TenantFrom, t2.Name AS TenantTo
from Tenants t1
INNER JOIN Tenants t2
ON t1.Bedrooms_Needed = t2.Current_Bedrooms 
AND t1.City_Needed = t2.Current_City
AND t1.TenantID <> t2.TenantID
WHERE t1.TenantID = 1234;
```

The tenant id exclusion is to prevent self-matches in the event of the tenant living in an exact match already.

**Edit, Re Mutual Matches**

In order to find pairs of mutually matching tenants, you will need to add the reciprocal criteria as additional filters:

```
Select T1.Name As TenantFrom, t2.Name AS TenantTo
from Tenants t1
INNER JOIN Tenants t2
ON t1.Bedrooms_Needed = t2.Current_Bedrooms 
AND t1.City_Needed = t2.Current_City
AND t1.Current_Bedrooms = t2.Bedrooms_Needed
AND t1.Current_City = t2.City_Needed 
AND t1.TenantID <> t2.TenantID
WHERE t1.TenantID = 1234;
```

Comment: Nice. thanks. That worked. How about mutual matches?

Comment: You just need to add the reciprocal criteria as well - I've updated.